# remove duplicates in a datatable from sql query

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

basically I have this code in sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.fDate FROM tblReport_Date A 
LEFT JOIN tblReport_Type B ON A.ID_ReportType = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblReceiver C ON A.ID_Receiver = C.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblClients D ON A.ID_Client = D.ID 
WHERE A.fDate BETWEEN '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND '6/1/2014 12:00:00 AM'
AND B.fType = 'HCC' AND C.Receiver = '<test@test.com>'
AND D.fClientName = 'Radford'
```

now, it would return

```
9/25/2013 8:00:00 AM
10/3/2013 12:00:00 PM
12/5/2013 10:00:00 AM
12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

what I wanted is something like

```
9/25/2013 8:00:00 AM
10/3/2013 12:00:00 PM
12/5/2013 10:00:00 AM
```

or even better

```
9/25/2013 12:00:00 AM
10/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

I know this is impossible in my current query, because

*12/5/2013 10:00:00 AM*  and  *12/5/2013 12:00:00 AM*

have different **TIME** values. Is this possible through query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by date (without time), this should work on most versions of SQL-Server starting with 2005:

```
SELECT fDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, A.fDate), 0) 
FROM tblReport_Date A 
LEFT JOIN tblReport_Type B ON A.ID_ReportType = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblReceiver C ON A.ID_Receiver = C.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblClients D ON A.ID_Client = D.ID 
WHERE A.fDate BETWEEN '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND '6/1/2014 12:00:00 AM'
AND B.fType = 'HCC' AND C.Receiver = '<test@test.com>'
AND D.fClientName = 'Radford'
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, A.fDate), 0)
```

Or in SQL Server 2008 onwards you  cast to  `Date`:

```
GROUP BY CAST(A.fDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: I can't accept it as an answer yet (needs 6 minutes to accept an answer bla blah), but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`;WITH CTE_Temp
(
SELECT DISTINCT A.fDate FROM tblReport_Date A 
LEFT JOIN tblReport_Type B ON A.ID_ReportType = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblReceiver C ON A.ID_Receiver = C.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblClients D ON A.ID_Client = D.ID 
WHERE A.fDate BETWEEN '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND '6/1/2014 12:00:00 AM'
AND B.fType = 'HCC' AND C.Receiver = '<test@test.com>'
AND D.fClientName = 'Radford'
) 
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(fDate) FROM CTE_Temp`

Comment: thanks bro.. there's some error, but its okay, the other one got the answer already  :D.. thanks by the way :)